# Google Charts - For a dynamic Line Chart, of to fix X axis on the last 10 entries

Tags: dynamic, charts, numbers, google-visualization

Google Charts - For a dynamic Line Chart, limit the number of entries in the X-Axis

While line chart is being generated on a continuos time line (i.e From "Time=0" to "Time=XXX" Dynamix) I would like to know who to simply fix the X-Axis to the last most recents 20 entries.

I have try putting a variable in the option declaration based on an index, put it simply does not take it..?

```
Var movingMax= (index)
Var movingMin= (index -20)

let options = {    width:  750,
                   height: 500,
                   title: "Brew-specs",
                   curveType: 'function',

                   hAxis:      {
                                 max:  movingMax,
                                 min:  movingMin
                               }
                 };
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `hAxis` option, `viewWindow` is missing. it should be...

```
hAxis: {
  viewWindow: {
    max:  movingMax,
    min:  movingMin
  }
}
```

also, the above option only works with a *classic* chart...

```
google.visualization.LineChart
```

it will not work with a *material* chart...

```
google.charts.Line
```